# When a statistical method requires a random sample, how do you know whether it is sampling with or without replacement?

Tags: sampling

For instance, when creating the sampling distribution for Central Limit Theorem, does it matter whether it is with or without replacement? Or what about wherever we assume i.i.d, does it matter then?

In another case, bootstrapping I know we sample (from the sample) *with* replacement, so it is important here.

But in general, how do we know whether to sample with or without replacement when generating random samples?

Comment: Sampling w/o replacement is incompatible with iid-ness.

Comment: This is exactly what I thought, but CLT assumes iid, and as far as my research goes CLT is still valid when sampling without replacement. So I'm getting incredibly confused?!

Comment: There are many versions of the CLT ... the most known (and thaught) is the iid version, but there are versions which admit some dependencies